# System.InvalidOperationException: Attaching an entity of type 'QC.Models.Defect' failed because another entity of the same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Look at my code

```
using (MyBridgeContext context = new MyBridgeContext())
                {
                    context.Users.Attach(user); //both working fine
                    context.Orders.Attach(order);

                    foreach (Defect def in defectList.Items)
                    {
                        if (defectList.SelectedItem == def)
                        {
                            context.Defects.Attach(def);//throwing error
                            defect = def;
                        }
                    }

                    DefectEntry entry = new DefectEntry();
                    entry.user = user;
                    entry.defect = defect;
                    entry.order = order;
                    entry.dt = DateTime.Now;

                    context.Entries.Add(entry);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    this.Content = new MainMonitoring(ref order, ref user);
                } <br />
```

When I am attaching user and order, it works fine even if such objects with their primary key exist in database(THAT IS THE REASON WHY I AM ATTACHING , I am not going to create a new object just attach it to ENTRY). But when I try to attach defect too, it throws that `System.InvalidOperationException` error. 
 
So this the combobox of Defects:(Program loads the list of defects and when user chooses it, it should be attached to the entry):

```
private void loadDefects()
    {
        MyRepository rep = new MyRepository();
        var defects = rep.GetDefects();
        foreach(var def in defects)
        {
            defectList.Items.Add(def);
        }
        defectList.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"; //defectList is comboBox
    } <br /> <br />
```

So this is MyRepository:

```
public class MyRepository
{
    public List<Defect> GetDefects()
    {
        MyBridgeContext context = new MyBridgeContext();
        return context.Defects.AsNoTracking().ToList(); //AsNoTracking doing nothing
    }
    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        MyBridgeContext context = new MyBridgeContext();
        return context.Users.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }
    public List<Order> GetOrders()
    {
        MyBridgeContext context = new MyBridgeContext();
        return context.Orders.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are attaching the `Defect`, then attaching it to a `DefectEntry` then attaching it again through attaching the `DefectEntry`?

Comment: Also just an aside, why use a repository with `AsNoTracking()` when you end up having to reattach entities? It doesn't seem like your repository is giving you anything of value, you can't even pass a predicate `Func<>` into the methods. I suggest you drop your repo pattern and only use `AsNoTracking()` when you are in an actual read only scenario.

Comment: @Wurd there is no again-again atttachment just once I try and it's getting failed.I getting defect from repository class and attaching it to defectentry to make defects per order (this is what actually defectentry does) .

Comment: The error message begs to differ.

Comment: @wurd how can you help me? if you want I can send my entire project in zip format and then maybe you get the real issue